# matching null with regex in xsd

Tags: regex, xsd

I want to allow null elements in xsd. Usually I do this with the nillable="true" attribute, but it doesn't work for elements like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="numbers">
<xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
<xs:pattern value="[0-9][0-9]"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I thought, that maybe there is a way to allow null elements with regex. Or should I do it with xsd?

Can you help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So you want your valid values to be any 0-, 1-, or 2-digit number? How extensive is the support for regular expressions in the `<xs:pattern/>` field? Can you do something like `<xs:pattern value="[0-9]{0,2}">`?

Comment: I have an input field, and I want to allow the user to enter either a 2-digit number or nothing.
I tried <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{0,2}">, and it works for 1 and 2 digits, but not for 0...

Comment: Well, if I change the xs:integer to xs:string, this one works:  
    <xs:pattern value="((\d{2})|([0-9]{0}))"/>